# python(anaconda) from exec() of php

Tags: python, php, anaconda

I try to call python from `exec()` of php on apache server.

I use `anaconda` for my environment.

```
<?php
$cmd = "conda activate myenv;python xxx.py";
exec($cmd,$output);
var_dump($output);
```

It shows

`array(0) { }`

but 
`conda activate myenv;python xxx.py` works in console and show json.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are running 2 commands:

```
conda activate myenv
python xxx.py
```

This means that $output will be an array. Try to use var_dump($output) to see the result.

Comment: If you run this two commands on the terminal, what return do you get?

Comment: It returns json like {"text":"mytext"}